# Codename One - GridLayout in a RTL language

Tags: codenameone

Is it possible to automatically "mirror" a GridLayout in a RTL language? I mean that the first column should be on right instead of on left.

I tried it in my app without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work. I'm guessing you didn't activate the global RTL flag correctly you need to do that early on in the app for it to take effect.

```
Form hi = new Form("RTL", BoxLayout.y());

Container grid = GridLayout.encloseIn(new Label("1"), new Label("2"), new Label("3"));
Container gridRTL = GridLayout.encloseIn(new Label("1"), new Label("2"), new Label("3"));
gridRTL.setRTL(true);

hi.addAll(grid, gridRTL);

hi.show();
```

[image]